# Is it possible to Get ArrayList from Another Class through this method?

Tags: android, arraylist

I am creating a small music player app. I have two classes named "Tab3Tracks" and "NowPlaying". I created an ArrayList in "Tab3Tracks" class. Now, I want to access the arraylist which is loaded with songs in "NowPlaying" class. Check my code for mistakes. I am getting error in accessing ArrayList.

**Tab3Tracks Class**

```
public class Tab3Tracks extends ListFragment {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private ArrayList<String> trackslist = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3tracks, container, false);


    final String trackid = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
    final String trackno = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK;
    final String trackname = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
    final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
    final String[] projection = {trackid,trackno,trackname,path
    };
    final Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri,projection,null,null,null);
    if (cursor!=null){
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int trackIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                trackslist.add(cursor.getString(trackIndex));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } cursor.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),R.layout.playlist_item,R.id.songTitle,trackslist
    );
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}


public ArrayList<String> getList(){
    return trackslist;
}



@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    int songIndex = position;

    // Starting new intent
    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlaying.class);
    // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
    in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
    getActivity().setResult(100, in);
    getActivity().finish();
    startActivity(in);
}
}
```

Is my method correct in accessing ArrayList from Another class ?

**NowPlaying Class**

```
  public class NowPlaying extends AppCompatActivity{

 public ArrayList<String> songsList = new ArrayList<String>();
 public Tab3Tracks songs1;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);
    // Getting all songs list
    songsList= songs1.getList();

 }
 }
```

**LogCat Runtime Error**

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.digital.thefearstuff.tfsmusicplayer.Tab3Tracks.getList()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please update the post with the **whole logcat** of the error.

Comment: @Vucko Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.digital.thefearstuff.tfsmusicplayer.Tab3Tracks.getList()' on a null object reference

Comment: Well apparently it's this line then `songsList= songs1.getList();` since you've not initialized `songs1` anywhere. It's null, and thus the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the method getlist() in a wrong way. You can get this from two methods:

**1)** Making Instance of the class(tab3tracks) in the class you want and then calling the method getlist().

```
Tab3tracks tab3 = new Tab3Tracks(); songslist = tab3.getlist();
```

**2)** Making the method static and then call it from another class without making instance of the class(tab3tracks)(which contains method getlist())

```
Tab3tracks.getlist();
```

*The error that you asked is that you have not made the getlist() static and you are calling it statistically.*

> **First Solution---**

***Tab3Track Class -:***

```
public class Tab3Tracks extends ListFragment {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public ArrayList<String> trackslist = new ArrayList<>();

public Tab3Tracks(){}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3tracks, container, false);


    final String trackid = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
    final String trackno = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK;
    final String trackname = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
    final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
    final String[] projection = {trackid,trackno,trackname,path
    };
    final Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri,projection,null,null,null);
    if (cursor!=null){
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int trackIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                trackslist.add(cursor.getString(trackIndex));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } cursor.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),R.layout.playlist_item,R.id.songTitle,trackslist
    );
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}


public ArrayList<String> getList(){
    return trackslist;
}



@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    int songIndex = position;

    // Starting new intent
    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlaying.class);
    // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
    in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
    getActivity().setResult(100, in);
    getActivity().finish();
    startActivity(in);
}
}
```

***NowPlaying Class:***

```
public class NowPlaying extends AppCompatActivity{

 public ArrayList<String> songsList = new ArrayList<String>();
 public Tab3Tracks tab3;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);
    // Getting all songs list
    tab3 = new Tab3Tracks();
    songsList= tab3.getList();

 }
 }
```

> **Second Solution:**

***Tab3Tracks Class:***

```
public class Tab3Tracks extends ListFragment {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public ArrayList<String> trackslist = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3tracks, container, false);


    final String trackid = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
    final String trackno = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK;
    final String trackname = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
    final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
    final String[] projection = {trackid,trackno,trackname,path
    };
    final Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri,projection,null,null,null);
    if (cursor!=null){
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                int trackIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                trackslist.add(cursor.getString(trackIndex));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } cursor.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),R.layout.playlist_item,R.id.songTitle,trackslist
    );
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}


public static ArrayList<String> getList(){
    return trackslist;
}



@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    int songIndex = position;

    // Starting new intent
    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlaying.class);
    // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
    in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
    getActivity().setResult(100, in);
    getActivity().finish();
    startActivity(in);
}
```

***NowPlaying Class:***

```
public class NowPlaying extends AppCompatActivity{

 public ArrayList<String> songsList = new ArrayList<String>();

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);
    // Getting all songs list
    songsList= Tab3Tracks.getList();

 }
 }
```

Comment: @Saini I am getting the array list size zero in "NowPlaying" class. But in other class, it shows a positive value

Comment: yes it will, because if you don't start the Tab3Tracks class, then ArrayList will be zero. It happens because ArrayList is created but not filled with values. So you will have to declare a another method in which ArrayList is filled up by the values and then it is retreived by the NowPlaying Class.